# Applying existing multi-material from a geometry node mesh

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I have a mesh, (in this example 4 planes joined together), each plane got a different material:

[image: reference image]

Is there an automatic way of telling geometry nodes to apply the same material as it was before without manually selecting and telling which material is assigned? Something like how "From Instancer" on Texture Coordinate worked before on an Image Texture which automatically changes the particle colour?

[image: reference image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do this setup:

[image]

I used **Transfer attribute** to get material index and set it into **set material index**

Instances should be realized to have an ability to set different materials for each object.

**Capture attribute** sets index per instance instead of per face.

Also, if you have an instance prepared with the same materials as the plane, you can simplify set-up like this:

[image]

Comment: oh wow! so that's how the material index works, thanks so much! I learned a lot from this :D

Answer (score 0):

Managing UVs and GeoNodes is notoriously kind of hard right now. Bu i know that the channel [Deafult Cube](https://www.youtube.com/c/DefaultCube/featured) had a workaround for this. But i cand find the video right now, so if you search for it for it, maybe youll find the answer.

Comment: I've been watching his vids along with other blender channels, so far haven't seen him tackle this. But it's all good, Crantisz got the answer I was looking for :D Thanks!