# GN: How to pass an instancer's localized texture color to its instances?

Tags: materials, uv, geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

How can Geometry Nodes be used to generate instances that inherit the texture color of their emitter/instancer?

Reference image of desired result:

[image]

(Above: screenshot by [quellenform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/145249/quellenform))

There is already [a solution using particle systems in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166916/2952). Now I am looking for a way to do it using Geometry Nodes (that will be compatible with Eevee as well).

Because the "From Instancer" checkbox on the Texture Coordinate node is only for Cycles, and because *particles* and GN *instances* are fundamentally different, a new approach is needed.

(I have found [an answer that uses the material index](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/261817/2952) to assign multiple materials, but using multiple materials is something else altogether, and would only work for images with a handful of colors.)

Comment: Note to contributors: Thank you all for the 3 (as of this writing) helpful answers! I did not anticipate such a swift response. While I have upvoted each of them, I am having trouble determining which should be the "accepted" answer. Since I want to be fair, I will take some time to try out the different methods. If one stands out as most optimal, I will accept it. If I don't accept any, consider it a tie. Reminder to the community: Please upvote any answer that helped you.

Comment: Expect the unexpected, here on blender.stackexchange.com and take the time you need ;-)

Comment: Overview: **quellenform**'s technique maps the texture to the *object bounds*. Since it doesn't rely on a UV map, the instances and the emitter plane *can be joined as one object* and still retain their texture mapping. **TheJeran**'s technique and **possibly ferret**'s technique are similar in that they both pull in a UV map through the modifier, allowing complex textured objects to be manipulated (not only planes). They differ in that the former *returns a color*, while the latter *returns the UV* (which allows for further manipulation of the vector within the material).

Comment: For people looking into controlling color on unrealized instances: it still seems impossible and all 3 answers here realize instances.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady True - all three answers realize instances. I didn't specify any criteria about this in the question, as my total poly count will probably not be high enough for that to be a constraint. Also, I don't know if it's possible to work around that limitation. Each instance would need to receive *some kind of unique data* that could then be decoded into UV or color data within the material. Maybe there is some trickery that can be done, and I'd be curious to see an answer like that.

Comment: @Mentalist if you can derive instance position from sampled point position in shader, then you can, otherwise you can't (yet): [Is where a way to pass data to material without realizing instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/253723/60486)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This variant is different because you do not need a UV map nor an existing ground plane. This is the case, for example, if you even want to create the grid on which you distribute the points in *Geometry Nodes*.

This is how I would solve it (*no external attributes required, all in one place controlled by Geometry Nodes* and independently displayable from the ground plane):

[image]

[image]

1. Use the node `Bounding Box` to capture the dimensions of the grid on which you want to instantiate the cubes.
2. Map these dimensions to a vector from $0,0,0$ to $1,1,1$ so that you can feed the node `Image Texture` correctly *(You can of course directly feed in an external attribute, like your UV map, if you already have one)*.
3. Then distribute the points with the node `Distribute Points on Faces` on your grid and instantiate your objects there.
4. The nodes `Random` and `Set Position` will help you to distribute them randomly on the *Z-axis* in a certain area.
5. Finally you only have to capture the color from the node `Image Texture` with the node `Capture Attribute` per instance and pass it to the *Group Output*, as well as define the materials.

In the shader, you can then retrieve and process the color transferred to the instances with the `Attribute` node *(in this example I also used another color for the sides of the cubes)*:

[image]

[image]

---

**Update**

[image]

...and here is an example and the reason why I prefer this variant: It is just super flexible and everything can be realized procedurally without UV mapping in *Geometry Nodes*:

[image]

Here's a [short video](https://youtu.be/eRBCUwS4qWc), since it doesn't look good in the GIF (Rendered with EEVEE).

And this is the node group that generates that:

[image]

Comment: Nice animation you added to your answer! It does a good job of illustrating what's possible. I'm playing with your node setup and I have a question: If one were to want to project the instances out from face normals (instances rotated according to faces) on a non-planar mesh (Suzanne, Torus, etc) and use the UV map to assign the texture, what would need to change?

Comment: @Mentalist Interesting idea! But I think that would almost be worth a separate question again, especially because the answer here would have to go into a bit of detail, don't you think?

Comment: Never mind. I achieved the result I wanted. Will share [my .blend file.](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1OMgqrja/) (Made with Blender 3.1.2) The instance rotation method is from [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/geometry-node-how-to-rotate-instance-along-faces/1334474). I borrowed and modified your animation technique. The coloring method is the same as in [TheJeran's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/264399/2952). There is the limitation of the instancer not being able to retain UV data if combined with the instances in a single object... so I simply used two separate objects.

Answer (score 5):

all you need to do is capture the UV attribute to the instances

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the answer :) Could you also post the shader node tree for completeness ?

Comment: it's in the blend file that you can download.

Answer (score 5):

The process is a bit tedious but it's quite simple.

First load in the texture you wanna use (I recommend Images as planes)
I have this image of africa so I'm gonna use that.

[image]

Next create your geometry node setup and distribute some points and instances.

[image]

Next we need to bring in the UV data. So click the Group tab and then create a new input.

[image]

Change it to Vector type. Then make the input an attribute and select UVMap

[image]

Now load your image texture into Geonodes and set-it up like I have here. You will need to create a new material to put in the set material node.

[image]

Give your new color output a name.

[image]

Lastly connect that attribute to the color in your shader.

[image]

VIOLA!

[image]

Comment: Hmm, and what would you do if you wanted to distribute the points on an object that you also created with Geometry Nodes?

Comment: You'd have to use your bounding box method as far as I know.

Comment: ....yes exactly, something like that, or exactly what I gave as an answer ;-)