# How to make geometry node instances inherit the shade of its emitter

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's say you have a bumpy plane with a diffuse material and you've populated it with a bunch of cube instances using geometry nodes.

Is it possible to get the color of the plane at each cube's position and then color the cubes accordingly? For example, cubes in the shadow will be black, while cubes in the light will be white.

Comment: Not dynamically.  You would need to bake the lighting to an animated image, after which you couldn't change the lighting without rebaking.  I don't think that's what you're after.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268934/geonodes-transfer-facet-color-to-instance-on-point-material-color/

Comment: Could your question be solved with the linked answer?