# How do you change the instance color to match the object's procedural color? Using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, instances

[image]

I'm looking for a similar effect found here:

[GN: How to pass an instancer's localized texture color to its instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264395/gn-how-to-pass-an-instancers-localized-texture-color-to-its-instances)

Instead of an image texture, I'd like to use a procedural texture that can be edited.

Comment: There is a setup in the answer where an image texture is used for the color... why don't you just place the procedural texture instead of the image texture? There is nothing in this setup that explicitly requires an image.

Comment: How do you place a procedural texture into geometry nodes?

Comment: Like in the _Shader Editor_... press `Shift` + `A` > _Add_ > _Texture_ > _Noise Texture_. If you don't know how to add nodes in GN, how did you actually planned to do something like that? Since you stated "Using geometry nodes" in the question's title and it didn't seem as if you were wondering how the image texture got in the other solution's nodetree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible solution (but there's probably a more elegant one):**

As long as you're fine with not using the same material for the plane and the instances, you don't really need to change anything in your geometry nodes.

For your plane, set the material like it is in your screenshot. For the instances, simply copy that material, but add an Object Info node to sample the noise texture at the position of the instance:
[image]

You can also encapsulate the Noise Texture, Color Ramp and BSDF into a node group that can be used by your plane and the instances, so they always use the same texture.

Comment: Thanks! This works! I can't believe I didn't think of it. I was too fixated on the other solution to see it.