# Create a row of duplicated cubes, each a different color

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm in the geometry node editor, using the *Duplicate Elements node*. For this example I duplicate a cube to create 100 cubes arranged in a line.

I would love to be able to use the *index* output of the node to choose a different material for each cube in the line. However, when I try to connect this output into anything determining a material, the connecting line is dotted red, and it fails to assign any material.

It seems like the *Set Material* node requires a constant input, not a variable input.

Is there a clean way to set a different material to a large number of duplicated or generated objects in the geometry node editor?

Comment: you can probably write the index into some sort of attribute and read this in your material. within the material you have to distinguish based on the index. but i guess _multiple_ materials is not possible yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying existing multi-material from a geometry node mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261568/applying-existing-multi-material-from-a-geometry-node-mesh) [single mesh with multiple colors per part in array](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288067/single-mesh-with-multiple-colors-per-part-in-array/288071#288071)

Comment: @Crantisz I was able to figure it out from your links, thank you. Realize Instances was the key